# Pandas: groupby index and then fill the dataframe using function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which is like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'pop1': ['1000', '2000','3000','4000'],
                   'pop2': ['2000', '3000','2000','2000']},
                  index=['female','female','male','male'])
```

How can I create a 2*2 DataFrame that gives the percent of the total population in a given year (the 2 columns) for a given gender (the two rows)?

Answer (score 4):

You need first cast `string` to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html), then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregating `sum` and divide by [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) by [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html). Last multiple `100`:

```
df = df.astype(int)

a = df.groupby(level=0).sum()
print (a)
        pop1  pop2
female  3000  5000
male    7000  4000

b = df.sum()
print (b)
pop1    10000
pop2     9000
dtype: int64

print (a.div(b).mul(100))
        pop1       pop2
female  30.0  55.555556
male    70.0  44.444444
```

It is same as:

```
df = df.astype(int)
print (df.groupby(level=0).sum().div(df.sum()).mul(100))
        pop1       pop2
female  30.0  55.555556
male    70.0  44.444444
```

Comment: Thanks! I have another question: if the female and male are all under an index name called "gender" and there is another category under this index called"both", which add the population of female and male together. When I use the groupby to calculate the percentage, how can I ignore that "both" category?

Comment: You need `df = df.astype(int).drop('both')` and `print (df.groupby(level='gender').sum() / df.sum() * 100)`

Comment: but there is question if both category has to be in df.sum() or not. Solution in comment before is if not.

Comment: if yes use `df = df.astype(int)` and `print (df.drop('both').groupby(level='gender').sum() / df.sum() * 100)`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a one liner:

```
(df.astype(int) / df.astype(int).sum()).groupby(level=0).sum() * 100
```

It is a little prettier if you are already dealing with integers:

```
df = df.astype(int)
(df / df.sum()).groupby(level=0).sum() * 100
```

Put into words, after you convert the data into integers, you then divide each number by the total size of the relevant population, sum up those weights for each gender, and then multiply by 100 so the result looks like a percentage.

Comment: Yours: 100 loops, best of 3: 1.79 ms per loop

Jezrael's: 100 loops, best of 3: 2.25 ms per loop

Answer (score 3):

```
v = df.values.astype(int)
pd.DataFrame(
    v / v.sum(0) * 100, df.index, df.columns
).groupby(level=0).sum()
```

[image]

Comment: Ahem! OP is newbie... Go easy on her @piRSqared! ;-)